# Puntero a N estructuras como parametro de funcion para devolver datos?

Tags: c++, c, punteros

Estoy haciendo un wrapper en C para acceder a una libreria hecha en C++.
La funcion original de la libreria tiene como parametros una serie de vectores de estructuras, algunos de salida y otros de entrada y salida. 
Necesito pasar un puntero para delvolver al wrapper y dentro de él reservar la memoria según los datos devueltos por la libreria.

Esta es la estructura que usa la libreria (C++) para devolverme los datos y la funcion a la que debo llamar

```
struct action {
    string name;
    int type;
    vector<unsigned char> data;
    int value;
    unsigned char source;
    unsigned char destination;
};

int my_function(vector<struct action> &actions)
```

Esta es la estructura creada en el wrapper y la funcion wrappeada

```
struct action_wpr {
    char *name;
    int type;
    key_wpr auth_key;
    unsigned char *data;
    int value;
    unsigned char source;
    unsigned char destination;
};
typedef struct action_wpr action_wpr;

another_struct_wpr *my_function_create(action_wpr *actions_out, unsigned char *nActions);
```

wrapper.cpp

```
another_struct_wpr *my_function_create(action_wpr *actions_out, unsigned char *nActions)
{
    // Instanciamos el vector de acciones para que lo rellene my_function()
    vector<struct action> actions;
    // Llamamos a la funcion de la library c++
    int ret = my_function(actions);
    // Pasamos a la estructura del wrapper los datos devueltos en el vector de acciones
    actions_out = (action_wpr*)malloc(actions.size() * sizeof(*actions_wpr));
    for (i=0; i<actions.size(); i++)
    {
        actions_out->name = actions[i].name;
        actions_out->type = actions[i].type;
        actions_out->value = actions[i].value; 
        actions_out->source = actions[i].source;
        actions_out->destination = actions[i].destination;
    }
    *nActions = actions.size();
}
```

Y llamo a esta funcion

```
action_wpr *acciones_out;
unsigned char nActions = 0;
my_function_create(acciones_out, &nActions);
```

Pero de esta forma, cuando intento recuperar los datos almacenados en el puntero despues de llamar a `my_function_create(acciones_out, &nActions);` me da una violacion del segmento.

Comment: Si editas la pregunta para aplicar cosas que te han dicho en las respuestas entonces las preguntas dejan de tener sentido... evita hacerlo en la medida de lo posible

Comment: @eferion tienes toda la razon. Iba a editar para dejarlo mas claro y lo he ensuciado mas.

Comment: No pasa nada, solo te lo comento para que lo sepas de cara a futuras preguntas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que dudo es de que tu programa compile siquiera:

```
    actions_out->name = actions[i].name;
```

`actions_out->name` es de tipo `char*`, mientras que `actions[i].name` es de tipo `std::string`... y **no existe** una conversión de `std::string` a `char*`. En cualquier caso, aunque funcionase, el código estaría mal porque `actions` es un contenedor que desaparece al salir de la función `my_function_create`, luego cualquier puntero a algún elemento de dicha estructura pasa a ser no válido... en este caso `actions_out->name`.

La solución pasa por hacer una reserva de memoria para la cadena:

```
actions_out->name = (char*)malloc(actions[i].name.size()+1);
strcpy(actions_out->name, actions[i].name.c_str());
```

Y por supuesto, después, en algún momento, habrá que acordarse de liberar esa memoria

```
for( int i=0; i<nActions; i++ )
  free(actions[i].name);
free(actions);
```

**Segundo problema**: El argumento `actions` **es local**, luego el puntero a la reserva de memoria que estás realizando se pierde al abandonar la función.

Se ve mejor si quitamos los punteros:

```
void func(int var)
{
  var = 5;
}

int main()
{
  int var = 0;
  func(var);
  std::cout << var;
}
```

¿Qué valor imprimirá el programa? Obviamente 0, ya que la asignación a 5 es un cambio de la copia de `var`. Para que el 5 se refleje fuera de la función tenemos que usar una referencia o un puntero:

```
void func(int *var)
{
  *var = 5;
}

int main()
{
  int var = 0;
  func(&var);
  std::cout << var;
}
```

Pues bien, si ahora resulta que `func` necesita modificar *un puntero* ... la función deberá recibir **un puntero doble**:

```
void func(int **var)
{
  *var = 5;
}

int main()
{
  int *var = 0;
  func(&var);
  std::cout << var;
}
```

Es decir:

```
another_struct_wpr *my_function_create(action_wpr **actions_out, unsigned char *nActions)
//                                                ~~ puntero doble
{
    // Instanciamos el vector de acciones para que lo rellene my_function()
    vector<struct action> actions;
    // Llamamos a la funcion de la library c++
    int ret = my_function(actions);
    // Pasamos a la estructura del wrapper los datos devueltos en el vector de acciones
    *actions_out = (action_wpr*)malloc(actions.size() * sizeof(*actions_wpr));
//  ~ modificamos el puntero simple

    for (i=0; i<actions.size(); i++)
    {
        // Nota que todas las asignaciones cambian
        (*actions_out)->name = actions[i].name;
        (*actions_out)->type = actions[i].type;
        (*actions_out)->value = actions[i].value; 
        (*actions_out)->source = actions[i].source;
        (*actions_out)->destination = actions[i].destination;
    }

    *nActions = actions.size();
}
```

Finalmente, y no menos importante... Tu función **no devuelve nada** pese a que especificas un tipo de retorno:

```
   another_struct_wpr* my_function_create( ...
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Ahí ya no te puedo ayudar porque no tengo forma de saber qué es lo que se debe retornar ahí... si resulta que la función no va a retornar nada, por favor, cambia a `void`

Comment: he realizado los cambios que comentas y solo me queda una duda pendiente. Si la reserva de memoria de ```*actions_out``` la realizo (como dices) en la funcion dentro de ```wrapper.cpp``` y es a la vuelta de esa llamada cuando extraigo los datos, ¿donde debo liberar esa memoria de reserva? Ahora, despues de extraer los datos me salta un error ```munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer``` y si libero la memoria con un ```free(acciones_out)``` despues de extraer los datos me aparece un error ```double free or corruption (fasttop)```

Comment: Si te aparece `double free` es porque estás intentando liberar la memoria dos veces... en algún sitio tendrás un `free` de más. Lo del puntero no válido... no sabría decirte sin un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema

Comment: recomendaría el uso de strncpy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258550/why-should-you-use-strncpy-instead-of-strcpy

En la misma respuesta proponen usar strncat como forma segura de copiar `char *`  a `char *`

Comment: @JoséManuelRamos conozco esa función,. No la he usado simplemente porque tengo que poner un límite al alcance de la respuesta, no obstante puedes editar tu pregunta y añadir esa información que probablemente sea bien recibida

Comment: Tiene pinta que al volver de ```*my_function_create(action_wpr **actions_out, unsigned char *nActions)``` se pierde el contenido de ```actions``` y por eso me da el error ```munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer```. Y al liberar la memoria me avisa de que ya ha sido liberada. Estoy viendo la manera de hacerlo con un puntero de tipo opaco para manejar las estructuras de C++ en mi código en C. ¿Creeis que seria la mejor solucion?

Comment: Piensa que al ser un puntero doble tienes que llamar a la función usando `&`. Ejemplo: `action_wpr * mis_actions; int num_actions=5; my_function_create(&mis_actions, &num_actions);`

Answer (score 2):

### Cambios estéticos para facilitar la explicación

Permíteme poder hacer unos cuantos cambios estéticos que me permitan trabajar con tus datos. No recomiendo usar `struct action` siempre, sino hacer un `typedef` que permita usar esta estructura como un único tipo. La llamaremos, por facilidad, `action`.
También pondré los `namespaces`, ya que es una mala práctica de programación demasiado extendida usar `using namespace std;` en alguna cabecera.

Y por último alinearé los tipos de datos por un lado y las variables por otro para placer visual. Todo esto mejorará notablemente tu forma de trabajar **leyendo código**, que es realmente el trabajo que vas a realizar más tiempo.

Tu tipo de dato de origen pasará a ser:

```
typedef struct s_action
{
    std::string                   name       ;
    int                           type       ;
    std::vector < unsigned char > data       ;
    int                           value      ;
    unsigned char                 source     ;
    unsigned char                 destination;
} action;
```

El poner los `;` alineados ayudará muchísimo de cara a un futuro cuando tengas que editar todos los datos secuencialmente, ya que con un editor que permita copiar en vertical, tendrás gran parte del trabajo hecho.

Posteriormente veo que haces un `typedef`, pero es que podías haberlo hecho desde antes (si es código heredado, haz *baby steps*: introduce el typedef, compila, y comprueba quién llama al `struct` con los errores de compilación, haces los cambios uno por uno quitando `struct` y listo)

```
typedef struct s_action_wpr
{
    char *          name       ;
    int             type       ;
    key_wpr         auth_key   ;
    unsigned char * data       ;
    int             value      ;
    unsigned char   source     ;
    unsigned char   destination;
} action_wpr;
```

Por amor a los debugguers, no pongas el mismo nombre al `typedef` que al `struct`.

Habrás visto también que al colocar el struct de esta manera, queda el tipo de datos unívocamente definido. Esto nos ayudará en la siguiente fase, que consiste en aprender hacer TDD en C para la migración de los datos de origen a los datos de destino.

### TDD en C para la migración de datos

Lo primero que tienes que testar es la migración en sí. No puedes picar un código sin pruebas, si lo haces, corres el riesgo de que acabes desarrollando Skynet y tu código tome conciencia de sí mismo.

Así que, para la migración, deberás crear una función que te permita introducir un `action` y devuelva un `action_wpr`. De ahí te darás cuenta que tendrás que hacer una función para migrar cada parte que no se migre de forma directa.

## Migración de `action` en `action_wpr`

Con un editor que permite la edición en vertical, puedes ver que los campos no son iguales, te sobra en `action_wpr` un campo (que nos has omitido, imagino, a propósito)

```
typedef struct s_action                        | typedef struct s_action_wpr
{                                              | {
    std::string                   name       ; |     char *          name       ;
    int                           type       ; |     int             type       ;
    std::vector < unsigned char > data       ; |     key_wpr         auth_key   ;
    int                           value      ; |     unsigned char * data       ;
    unsigned char                 source     ; |     int             value      ;
    unsigned char                 destination; |     unsigned char   source     ;
} action;                                      |     unsigned char   destination;
                                                 } action_wpr;
```

Así que voy a quitarlo a propósito, porque no hay forma de hacer el traspaso fácilmente:

```
typedef struct s_action                        | typedef struct s_action_wpr
{                                              | {
    std::string                   name       ; |     char *          name       ;
    int                           type       ; |     int             type       ;
    std::vector < unsigned char > data       ; |     unsigned char * data       ;
    int                           value      ; |     int             value      ;
    unsigned char                 source     ; |     unsigned char   source     ;
    unsigned char                 destination; |     unsigned char   destination;
} action;                                      | } action_wpr;
```

Mucho mejor.

¿Qué vemos que podemos traspasar sin hacer cambios? Pues los `unsigned char`, los `int`.

Nota: ¿Has visto que haya puesto una sola línea de código? No, a esto se le llama pensar antes de actuar, te acostumbrarás cuando te pase mil veces, así que asume siempre que lo haces mal. Cuando seas capaz de cambiar tu forma de hacer las cosas habrás pasado al siguiente nivel. No es un ataque, es un consejo.

¿Qué datos necesitas para terminar la migración **que aún no hemos hecho**? `std::string` y `std::vector < unsigned char >` en, respectivamente, `char *` y `unsigned char *`

## Migrar `std::string` en `char *`

¿Conoces las propiedades de `std::string`? ¿Y las de `char *`? Viendo tu código, asumo que, efectivamente, no.

- No son la misma "cosa"
- `std::string` no es una forma de guardar caracteres uno detrás de otro, guardas cadenas de caracteres. Está indicado para guardar trozos de texto, y puedes realizarle operaciones de manipuación de cadenas de caracteres de forma directa con sus operadores.
- `char *` es un puntero a un "vector" de una dimensión de elementos de `char`, igual que cuando estudias en matemáticas los vectores, van unos detrás de otros. Alguno de ellos puede ser `\0`, `0xFF` o incluso `0xDE 0xAD 0xBE 0xEF`, que puede quedar como `0xDEADBEEF`, una referencia bastante habiutal en variables hexadecimales por su significado en inglés (vaca muerta).

Entendiendo que no son la misma cosa, ahora tienes que hacer una función a la que le pases el tipo de dato de un lado y devuelva el del otro con el contenido de entrada.

Ejemplos de tests que vas a tener que hacer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

char * funcion_migracion (std::string);

void test_harness_01 (void)
{
    /** Datos con los que voy a probar **/
    char * dato_char;
    char comparador_base[] = "test de prueba 01";

    /** Ejecución de la prueba **/
    dato_char = funcion_migracion ( std::string ( comparador_base ) ); // Al hacer esto, haces la conversión explícita de `char[]` a `std::string`, aunque no haría falta porque `funcion_migracion` sólo acepta `std::string` y lo convertiría internamente por ti

    /** Comprobar resultados esperados **/
    if ( dato_char == NULL )
    {
        printf("dato_char no puede ser NULL\r\n");
        return;
    }
    if ( strcmp(dato_char, comparador_base) != 0 )
    {
        printf("no se obtiene el restulado esperado\r\n");
    }

    /** Limpieza de los resultados obtenidos **/
    if ( dato_char != NULL )
    {
        free ( dato_char );
    }
}
```

Ahora pones diferentes resultados copiando y pegando la función `test_harness_01` y modificando `comparador_base` para ir viendo que te sale lo que tiene que salir. Mientras no salgan las pruebas, quiere decir que tu código no está bien hecho.

¿Qué obtienes con esto? Aprendes a hacer pruebas, sabes exactamente qué quieres y siempre que ejecutes los tests, volverás a comprobar que no has roto nada en el camino. Como habrás imaginado, estas pruebas no se ejecutan en tu programa real, se ejecutan en un lugar separado de tu programa, al que vamos a llamar "espacio de desarrollo". Te ayuda a que, cuando tengas que hacer o romper algo, tengas presente qué rompes y qué no, y mejora tu forma de realizar código a largo plazo. Dado que parece que estás aprendiendo a programar, tener esta forma de realizar programas es una herramienta de lo más útil para tu día a día.

Sabiendo esto, ya puedes, como ejercicio, saber cómo migrar un `std::vector` de `unsigned char`s en un `unsigned char *`.

## Migrar `std::vector < unsigned char >` en `unsigned char *`

¿Por qué no es tan fácil la migración y te has quedado atascado? Efectivamente, porque te has olvidado de un detallito sin importancia que los tests nos enseñarán llegado el momento.

Voy a plantearte el siguiente entorno de tests para que lo veas por ti mismo, y veas qué ocurre.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

char * funcion_migracion_vector (std::vector < unsigned char >);

void test_harness_vector_01 (void)
{
    /** Datos con los que voy a probar **/
    char * dato_char;
    std::vector < unsigned char > comparador_base;

    comparador_base.push_back('\0');

    /** Ejecución de la prueba **/
    dato_char = funcion_migracion_vector ( comparador_base );

    /*
     * ¿Qué demonios tiene que ocurrir aquí?
     */
}
```

Acabas de descubrir que, por construcción, ¡un `std::vector` de `unsigned char`s permite insertar `\0` en cualquier parte! ¿Y cómo podemos procesar los datos que hay detrás de `\0`? ¿Uso magia vudú?

Necesitarás, inevitablemente, un contador de todos los elementos de ese `vector`.

Y así es como se averiguan bugs de base que tienes en tu código y que desconocías. Igual que desconozco si eres profesional o no, sólo así salen estos errores, cuando haces pruebas (si las automatizas, directamente triunfas).

Una vez sabes cómo migrar los datos "difíciles" de migrar, hay que hacer el test de integración, que es migrar de una estructura a otra.

## Migrar desde `action` hasta `action_wpr`

En TDD se usa, llegado a este punto, una cosa que llamaremos `mock`s, que permiten engañar al sistema para no hacer todas las llamadas internas (por ejemplo, engañar al sistema para que no llame a una base de datos, que es una operación lenta y costosa), como esto me huelo que va para wiki de comunidad, te lo pondré fácil y seguiremos con las pruebas sencillas, ahora tus estructuras pasarán, con el bug que mencioné antes, a esto:

```
typedef struct s_action                        | typedef struct s_action_wpr
{                                              | {
    std::string                   name       ; |     char *          name       ;
    int                           type       ; |     int             type       ;
    std::vector < unsigned char > data       ; |     unsigned char * data       ;
                                               |     unsigned int    n_data_elms;
    int                           value      ; |     int             value      ;
    unsigned char                 source     ; |     unsigned char   source     ;
    unsigned char                 destination; |     unsigned char   destination;
} action;                                      | } action_wpr;
```

Aquí tendrías el código con el que tendrías que hacer la prueba para la migración entre estructuras:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

typedef struct s_action                       
{                                             
    std::string                   name       ;
    int                           type       ;
    std::vector < unsigned char > data       ;

    int                           value      ;
    unsigned char                 source     ;
    unsigned char                 destination;
} action;                                     

typedef struct s_action_wpr
{
    char *          name       ;
    int             type       ;
    unsigned char * data       ;
    unsigned int    n_data_elms;
    int             value      ;
    unsigned char   source     ;
    unsigned char   destination;
} action_wpr;



action_wpr * funcion_migracion_structs (action);

void test_harness_migration_structs_01 (void)
{
    /** Datos con los que voy a probar **/
    action_wpr * dato_char;
    action base;

    base.name("namestring prueba 01");
    base.type = 0xDEADBEEF;
    base.data.push_back('h');
    base.data.push_back('\0');
    base.data.push_back('l');
    base.data.push_back('a');
    base.data.push_back(' ');
    base.data.push_back('m');
    base.data.push_back('u');
    base.data.push_back('n');
    base.data.push_back('d');
    base.data.push_back('o');
    base.value = -35;
    base.source = 0x33;
    base.destination = 0xCC;

    /** Ejecución de la prueba **/
    dato_char = funcion_migracion_vector ( base );

    /*
     * ¿Qué demonios tiene que ocurrir aquí?
     */
}
```

Como has visto, he dejado sin completar. ¿Qué faltaría?

Pues, con esto, puedes hacer la migración entre elemento y elemento. Tu siguiente y último paso, ahora que ya sabes cómo se testa en escalera, directamente será testar cómo se migra un "vector" de elementos de un tipo a otro.

### Qué has aprendido

Has aprendido con esto que uno no se pone a programar a lo loco. Si tienes que migrar una estructura, haz pruebas para que dicha migración (migración como sinónimo de traspaso, de traductor, de conversor) esté siempre controlada.

Hay montones de frameworks que funcionan estupendamente en C y C++ para este fin. Y dado que los compiladores de C++ admiten código en C (usando extern 'C'), no tendrías problemas de ningún tipo en usar un framework de testing en C++, por ejemplo.

Mi respuesta no te hace código por ti. Ni pretendo que lo haga. Lo que hago es que veas qué problemática tienes a la hora de realizar código y una posible solución a corto y medio plazo que te ayudará.

Comment: Cierto, pero es que habia hecho un errático copy/paste al poner en mi pregunta un código simplificado.

Comment: Ahora tendré que borrar/editar mi respuesta porque, obviamente, ya no es válida.

Comment: Disculpame josé Manuel. No caí en el alcance que tendría corregir algunos puntos de mi pregunta. Lo tendré en cuenta para un futuro

Comment: No te preocupes, @crossmax, he editado la respuesta con algo más de información. Espero que puedas aprender algo útil de esto. Un saludo.

Comment: Sigo todavia ojiplatico @josé-manuel-ramos. Te agradezco mucho todo el tiempo que te has tomado. Ahora estoy replanteandome mas que mi código, mi manera de hacer las cosas asique no puedo ni tirar una linea. Apunto cada detalle para ternelo en cuenta. Gracias por esta ayuda desinteresada

Comment: He intentado condensar la problemática de tu pregunta en una respuesta que permita ayudarte tanto a ti como a otras personas que estén en tu misma situación. No hace falta que apuntes, lo que quiero es que te enteres, y espero haber utilizado un lenguaje apropiado para que pudieras progresar en la lectura de forma amena. Es muy complicado traspasar estos conocimientos sin una forma de saber que no necesitas volver para atrás, de ahí lo que he intentado hacer: enseñarte un paso que en software no se suele enseñar, y es el testar.

Comment: Si consideras mi respuesta apropiada o la de @eferion, márcala como válida